# Can I do an assignment operation between two istream_iterators?

Tags: c++

Can I do an assignment operation between two istream_iterators? If so then what will be the behaviour, i.e. will both the iterators point to the same location in the file, i.e. will we get two pointers to the same line in a file?

If so, can I increment one iterator, read some lines, and then assign it back to other iterator and then again start reading lines from the same location where we were earlier?

Basically I want to write a program that simulates for loop. But this should happen while parsing a file.

Answer (score 6):

istream_iterators are *input iterators*, not *forward iterators*. This means that they are single-pass iterators, as opposed to multi-pass iterators: there is no way to go back in the sequence, or to iterate the sequence more than once.

Comment: Specifically, you *can* copy and assign them, but incrementing one will invalidate any copies of it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: see my comment to Steve Jessop -- I believe copies remain valid (but incrementing one affects what others will retrieve).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: It looks like you're right; I was just looking at the InputIterator requirements, but (by accident or design) stream iterators seem to be required to remain dereferencable. It's not specified what you'll get from them, though.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I think it is. Earlier in the same passage, it specifies that it reads data "using >>".

Comment: @JerryCoffin: So it does. Looking in more detail, `*` should continue to return the old value, and `++` should read from the new position. I'd be rather nervous about relying on that behaviour, though.

Comment: I just wrote a sample code to check this. Copy works and after assignment also it prints the assigned value. But doing a ++ operation after this assignment is not resulting in the line after assignment, instead it is resulting in a line where the iterator is pointing before assignment. For example lets start reading file up to 3 lines and here do a copy in to other iterator and then proceed up to n lines and then do a assignment operation with the other iterator and print value. It prints stored value but after this ++ is not resulting in line after assigned value.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an `istream_iterator`, *but* an `istream_iterator` doesn't really refer to a specific location in the file, just to the current location, whatever that may be. As such, what you're contemplating won't work -- any iterator you use will just keep reading from the current point, not go back to the place it referred to when you saved it.

Comment: Is that guaranteed, or is it possible for the copy that you didn't increment to get FUBARed because the stream isn't necessarily in the exact state it expects?

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, I believe it's guaranteed (§24.5.1/1): "The result of operator* on an end of stream is not defined. For **any other** iterator value a const T& is returned." [emphasis added].

Comment: Hmm, I think that implicitly means an iterator value that has not been invalidated. In general an input iterator is invalidated when you increment a copy of it.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I don't see anything saying that about `istream_iterator`s.

Comment: 24.6.1/1 (`[istream.iterator]`) says that `istream_iterator` is an input iterator. I don't see anything explicitly forbidding it from behaving how you describe, but I also don't see anything to guarantee that an invalidated `istream_iterator` will continue to read from the current position of the stream. I suspect (without checking) that plenty of other places in the standard talk about what iterators do, for example what `std::vector<T>::iterator::operator*` does, without explicitly mentioning "unless you invalidated the iterator first" every time.

Comment: Does this drags to the conclusion that I can not use istream_iterator for my requirement. But on the other hand I want to do it on fly. I don't want to store the entire file content in a vector<string> and play with it. This is bad approach especially if the file is too big. Is there any other solution for this? My input file will be in XML format. Can I use DOM parsers to get my job done?

Comment: @suresh: Yes -- regardless of the other details, it won't work for what you want. A DOM parser also reads all the data into memory (at least all of which I'm aware do).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Then what would be the best solution in this case? I just started thinking of how parsing is done using lex and yacc parsers and thought of implementing it for my requirement. I hope in lex and Yacc cases entire file is not read in to memory. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @suresh: lex/yacc just read data; it's up to you to decide what to do with it afterwards (specifically, what/how much to keep/discard). For XML, you might consider a SAX parser.